# How can I redirect NON HTTP/NON HTTPS traffic to a specified IP with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, cloudflare, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have website and some game server.
I have domain which I connect to Cloudflare.

I want to redirect non http/https traffic to my server IP because when I try to connect to server with domain I can't do this because of Cloudflare proxy.

Maybe it can be done differently?

I use Nginx.

Comment: Nginx can reverse proxy arbitrary protocols using [the stream module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html).

Comment: @RichardSmith but not on subdomains, right?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare has its own SSL configuration.
There are 4 options for you:

- `Off` disables https completely
- `Flexible` Cloudflare will automatically switch client requests from HTTP to HTTPS but it still points to port 80 on your nginx server, should not configure SSL on nginx in this case.
- So the only options for you are `Full` or `Full Strict` (more restricted on the cert configured on nginx, must be a valid cert).

With `Full` you can configure your nginx with a self-signed SSL and let it go. Cloudflare will handle the part between client and its proxy server.